# Do I have to erase the system files from my old HDD when adding an SSD with the system on it?

Tags: system-installation, ssd, disk

I've been using Ubuntu 18.04 for almost two years now on my Acer Aspire One 5755G, and in a couple of days I will be getting a new SSD for it. The system right now is on a Toshiba HDD with some files and other stuff. **I will not be proceeding to swap the files from HDD to SSD as I find the process quite tideous and risky**, because I am not an advanced user by any means, so I decided to **install a new, clear OS on my SSD** - Ubuntu 18.04, too, and will be upgrading to 20.04 when the time is right. My question is, **do I have to erase the old system files from the HDD if I will be booting from the SSD from now on?** Will they interfere with the new system files or is it completely fine to let them stay there? **It is not necessary for me to delete them when it comes to the disk space they occupy** as I won't fill up both of the disks, just wondering if they will be risky to keep.

Comment: No, they will not interfere with the running system. However, during the installation on the SSD, the installer will notice that there is a complete and bootable installation already on the HDD. From that point on, at every reboot, it will give you a choice between booting the old system on the HDD and the new one on the SSD. You may want to skip that part, so after a successful installation, you may want to delete the old operating system.

Comment: What size is your HDD? What size is the new SSD?

Comment: I like to keep a working system on every drive, just for emergency boot. Usually in a smaller / (root) partition as it does not have all my added in applications.

Comment: My HDD is 320GB and the SSD will be 240GB. I would like to keep some files like photos and documents on the HDD while running the OS and some games from the SSD, that's why I was wondering if the system being present on both of the disks would be a problem. If I were to delete the old OS, as Jos said, how should I proceed?

Comment: After your new system is up and running, mount the HDD (e.g. as `/mnt/hdd`), delete all of your folders from the old system except for `/mnt/hdd/home` (which is where your photos and documents will be). For convenience, move all the files from `/mnt/hdd/home/[username]/` two layers up to `/mnt/hdd/`, delete the now empty `/mnt/hdd/home/[username]` and `/mnt/hdd/home/`. At that point, you could even create a mount point in your new system's home directory and mount the drive, which now only contains your photos and documents, as a separate folder like `~/myoldhdd`.

Comment: If you want the system to boot into the SSD with no questions asked, use `gparted` to remove the *bootable*  flag from the HDD and update `grub`. But that's another story.

Comment: Will see how the process goes next week and I'll get you know if I needed some more help. Hopefully everything goes right. Anyways, thank you for help, Jos :)